# Is a SSD with the following First Aid report salvageable?

Tags: imac, disk-utility, ssd, external-disk

Barely 2 months old [Samsung NVMe M.2 SSD](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-970-pro-nvme-m2-512gb-mz-v7p512bw/) is not readable by my Mac anymore. This is an external disk in an enclosure. I purchased a different enclosure too to confirm that the problem is with SSD only.

Following is the result of running First Aid on it:

[image]

---

As you may have noticed, the device shows up twice in the Disk Utility. When I try running First Aid on the second entry for the device, I get the following result:

[image]

---

My question:

Is there any way I can salvage the data on this SSD?

Does anyone here have some trick up their sleeve to fix this without attempting a format/erase?

Comment: I suspect that you will need to erase the whole disk to make it useable again. Salvaging data from SSDs is much harder than with mechanicals. You really need to rely on backups.

Comment: @benwiggy: :-( That’s my decade old photos collection and some part of office work.

Comment: If it's decades old, was it not on some other disk first? SSD data recovery is possible, but more difficult, and probably more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

There are several data recovery programs for the Mac. A few are [Stellar Recovery](https://www.stellarinfo.com/gdc/mac-data-recovery/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwzbv7BRDIARIsAM-A6-3Ba6aYPJUMCg9jDbZuhid0KX0-rq9t7ymBe9jHQpBm6TNdsQDDrpkaAtbkEALw_wcB), [EASEUS](https://www.easeus.com/ad/recover-hard-drive.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQjwzbv7BRDIARIsAM-A6-2nSQqlk28S7tFjiyzf_TGQ8xyuwJImWrij3nc5Upwb4hy4g0NMWIsaAojMEALw_wcB), and [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/help/ssd-data-recovery-mac/).  There are several others as well. A google search on "Mac data recovery ssd" will find these and more. Most of these are not cheap. Often in the $50-$60 range. Several may offer free trials though so you can test the app and maybe recover your data in one trial.

I can't really recommend one over the others. I used Stellar once and it recovered some of my data off my HDD.  SSDs are more difficult.

Comment: Is there any way I can fix the SSD without having to format it or doing a data recovery?